Unable to Seed Database in Next.js 14 Using Drizzle ORM with Neon PostgreSQL
I'm working on a project using Next.js 14, and I'm trying to seed my PostgreSQL database (hosted on Neon) using Drizzle ORM. Despite following the documentation, my seeding script isn't working as expected. Here's my setup:

Setup:
Next.js version: 14.x.x
Node.js version: v16.14.0
Drizzle ORM version: drizzle-orm@latest
Database: PostgreSQL (hosted on Neon)

import "dotenv/config";
import { drizzle } from "drizzle-orm/neon-http";
import { neon } from "@neondatabase/serverless";
import * as schema from "../db/schema";

const sql = neon(process.env.DATABASE_URL!);
// @ts-ignore
const db = drizzle(sql, { schema });

const seedDatabase = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log("Seeding database");

    // Delete existing data
    await Promise.all([
      db.delete(schema.userProgress),
      db.delete(schema.challenges),
      db.delete(schema.units),
      db.delete(schema.lessons),
      db.delete(schema.courses),
      db.delete(schema.challengeOptions),
      db.delete(schema.userSubscription),
    ]);

    // Insert data
    const courses = await db
      .insert(schema.courses)
      .values([{ title: "Stretching", imageSrc: "/stretching.svg" }])
      .returning();

    for (const course of courses) {
      const units = await db
        .insert(schema.units)
        .values([{ courseId: course.id, title: "Unit 1", order: 1 }])
        .returning();

      // More seeding logic here...
    }

    console.log("Database seeded successfully");
    res.status(200).json({ success: true });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Database seeding error:", error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Failed to seed database" });
  }
};

export default seedDatabase;


Problem:
The API route (or the custom script) runs, but the database doesn't seem to be seeded correctly.
The DATABASE_URL is correctly set in the .env file.
I've confirmed the database connection using other tools like pgAdmin.
Error Log:
Database seeding error: [Error: Failed to seed database]
Ensured that the environment variable DATABASE_URL is loaded properly.
The Neon database is online and accessible.
Checked the schema in Drizzle ORM, and it appears to be correct.
